# Setting a constant speed to Processing vectors

Tags: java, vector, processing

I'm having a vector follow mouse clicks in processing:

```
friendlies.get(i).setXSpeed((friendlies.get(i).getmx()-friendlies.get(i).getX())/100);

friendlies.get(i).setYSpeed((friendlies.get(i).getmy()-friendlies.get(i).getY())/100);
```

`friendlies.get(i`) is the vector and `getmx()` returns where the mouse was when it clicked.
The only problem is that the speed decreases as the vectors gets closer to its destination, I can't figure out how to make the speed constant.

Comment: Maybe you are calculating the (difference/100) each iteration? The difference decreases, so the speed does as well. You need to e.g. remember the initial difference and reuse this in each iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

- 1) obtain *direction vector* (from element towards mouse click)
- 2) normalize this direction vector to **unit vector**
- 3) use this unit vector as speed (you can multiply it by some constant factor)

  ```
  PVector pos = friendlies.get(i);

  // direction vector
  PVector dir = new PVector(mouseX - pos.x, mouseY - pos.y);

  // now it becomes unit-vector (with length 1)
  dir.normalize();

  pos.x = pos.x + dir.x * factor;
  pos.y = pos.y + dir.y * factor;
  ```